# Is dynamic scheduling better or static scheduling (Parallel Programming)?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, scheduling

I understand my question title is rather broad, I am new to parallel programming and openmp. I tried to parallelize a [C++ solution](https://github.com/pramttl/cs575-project2/blob/master/project2.cpp) for the N-body problem and study it for different schedule types and granularity. I collected data by running a program for different cases and plotted the data, this is what I got (Performance vs Number of threads) ([Performance](https://github.com/pramttl/cs575-project2/blob/master/project2.cpp#L166) can be assumed to be proportional to MegaFLOPS.)

[image]

> Performance vs Number of Threads

I was surprised to see that **static scheduling** generally did better than **dynamic scheduling** for this problem? Can anyone explain the possible reasons for this behavior?

Comment: As with most source of (unexpected) performance degradation in parallel programs, communication costs may be higher due to dynamic scheduling. Perhaps your problem size is not near enough for dynamic scheduling to outperform static. You'll need to dig deeper and explain the "performance" (what metric are you using?).

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: The performance metric I am using is (NUMBODIES * NUMBODIES*NUMSTEPS) / (runtime of parallel part i.e i,j loops)

Here is a reference to it in the code: https://github.com/pramttl/cs575-project2/blob/master/project2.cpp#L166

Comment: You should also try different chunk sizes or guided scheduling. Dynamically dispatching chunks of size 1 can be very costly.

Comment: @VladimirF But will that effect the relative performance? (I am not trying to performance tune my code but just trying to understand why is static scheduling doing relatively better than dynamic scheduling). I'll try to change chunk-size and see.

Comment: Yes, it can change the relative performance, the chunk size is pretty important.

Comment: It's a good first step to start experimenting, now you just have to try and understand the reason why dynamic scheduling is often preferred. Three are definitely problems where static scheduling is the way to go and n-body is a nice example of such a thing - in the best case dynamic scheduling will do as good as static scheduling, but not better. Question: How much does the running time differ between different iterations of your loop and why would that be important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results are not that revelant to notice a strong difference between the dynamic and static approach scheduling. I find measuring [speedup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) more appropriate in your context where you want to see the behaviour of your parallel scalability. You can also use different metrics such as [weak and strong scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Weak_versus_strong_scaling).

You hardly reach a speedup of 2 using both scheduling with the coarse grained approach. This is not enough to conclude anything. Moreover,
you cannot analyze your results from your fine grained implementation since you have no parallel gain from it (this can be explained by the poor workload you have for each thread). Get good parallel scalability first.

Generally I choose the static or dynamic scheduling depending on the type of computations I am working on :

- Static scheduling where computation workload is regular (the same for each thread) such as basic image convolution, naive matrix computation. For instance, using static scheduling for [gaussian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) should be the best option.
- Dynamic scheduling where the computation workload is irregular such as Mandelbrot set. The way dynamic works is a little more complex (chunks are not precomputed as in static scheduling) hence some overhead might appear.
- Guided scheduling is quite similar to dynamic scheduling but starts with large chunk size and decreases through time.

In your case, your nbody simulation implies quite regular works. So static scheduling should be more appropriate. Having good parallel scalability is sometimes empirical and depends of your context.

I recommend that in the first place, you let OpenMP choose the best scheduling and chunk size for you, then try to play with things if needed.

Comment: Good answer. So I like the take away idea i.e. if the work load for each thread is more or less the same then static scheduling tends to do better (maybe because dynamic scheduling has an overhead of having one thread assigned as the master thread to coordinate with the other threads). And for irregular workloads, threads would be ideal if we used static scheduling, so it would be better to use dynamic for this case.